# How to fetch/make realtime data connection from firebase v9 for the onSubmit function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Below is the onSubmit function that needs to be fetched from firestore, What should be the code in firebase-v9 for the same?

```
const onSubmit = (formData) => {
console.log(formData)
db.collection('emails').add({
  to: formData.to,
  subject: formData.subject,
  message: formData.message,
  timestamp: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()
});

dispatch(closeSendMessage());
```

};

Answer (score 0):

The following code in V8

```
db.collection('emails').add({
  to: formData.to,
  subject: formData.subject,
  message: formData.message,
  timestamp: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()
});
```

becomes the following in V9:

```
import { collection, addDoc, serverTimestamp } from "firebase/firestore"; 

addDoc(collection(db, "emails"), {
  to: formData.to,
  subject: formData.subject,
  message: formData.message,
  timestamp: serverTimestamp()
});
```

See [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart#initialize) for instructions on how to declare `db`.

Comment: It is giving me parsing error now as Unexpected reversed word "await".

Comment: In your case you can remove it. However I would recommend reading about asynchronous JavaScript, because most of the Firebase methods are asynchronous and return promises. See https://blog.logrocket.com/understanding-asynchronous-javascript/

Comment: Hey @PriyanshuPandey did you have the time to look at my last comment. If my answer solved your problem please upvote and accept it. Thks

Comment: No , It doesn't work for my file i am getting blank screen now.

Comment: @Priyanshu Is Firestore returning the data? (do a console.log). Also please check the security rules and the dependencies required for v9.